# Python: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED, Windows

Tags: python, certificate, urllib2

I have a script that is throwing a CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED on one of the PCs available to me, but not the other. The certificate was updated last week. How do I check if there is a cached version of the certificate somewhere, and get it refreshed?

I tried manually updating the .pem file in the lib/site-packages/certifi folder but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try running command `pip install certifi`

Comment: Thanks for responding. I already installed certifi, I'm still getting the same result.